# Nested Delete in MySql based on Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a database containing all the content updates for a CMS driven website.  I want to create a query that will clean out all the old stuff, but leave me the most recent few (5) copies of each page (just in case).  The table contains a TIMESTAMP field, and a PAGE ID field to help me find the right rows.  The PrimaryKey is a field called RevisionId.  There are of course other fields (containing the page content for example), but they are irrelevant to this question.

I have this query working fine:

```
  SELECT RevisionId 
    FROM `content` 
   WHERE PageId='55' 
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 5;
```

It returns five entries that I wish to save.

I thought I could nest it like this:

```
DELETE 
  FROM `content` 
 WHERE PageId='55' 
   AND RevisionId NOT IN ( 
           SELECT RevisionId 
             FROM `content` 
            WHERE PageId='55' 
         ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 5 );
```

...but that gives me an error:

**#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'**

I am running MySQL 5.

Two part question:

1. What do I need to do to resolve the error I am getting thus far?
2. Is there a way to further automate this to run through my
   entire table...not just PageId='55'
   but all distinct PageId numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently mysql can't process delete statements with subqueries to the same table. You need to create temporary table to get list of most recent rows and then use it in a subquery.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to step out of MySQL and use PHP to run a series of commands to make the database, then perform the deletions, then delete the temp database?...This is specifically what I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: @techtheatre: Is it not possible to run a multi-statement MySQL query from PHP?

Comment: It is...I was just hoping I could do the whole thing in a single set of nested queries or something.  It seems that I will have to do this in PHP, which is totally fine...I was just hoping there was a more "native" way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild try:

```
DELETE c FROM `content` AS c WHERE PageId='55' AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM `content` WHERE PageId='55' AND c.RevisionId = content.RevisionId ORDER BY content.Timestamp DESC LIMIT 5 );
```

Comment: ERROR:  #1093 - You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause